# Periodically sending notification to user in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, background, push-notification

**Goal**: Continuously send new notifications to user even after the application has been closed or a phone has been restarted.

**Details**: I am creating a motivational app which will send users a new quote or message every once in a while.

*The idea is* the user will download the app, and set preferences through the app for how often he/she would like to receive notifications. Then, there will likely be no reason for the user to visit the app again so it would just remain in the background.

How do I implement this feature so that the app sends notifications even if the app hasn't been opened in months and isn't even running in the background (ex. after a phone restart).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using push notifications or local notifications?

Answer (score 1):

As Troy asked above, push or local notifications?

If you use local notifications (scheduled on the device), take a look at [UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/). You would have to schedule all your notifications while the app is running though. For example:

```
var notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.alertBody = "Motivational Quote Here"
notification.fireDate = launchDate //time the notification will go off
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

If the user adjusted the setting for frequency of the quotes, you can delete a scheduled notification with

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
```

If the user did interact with the notification in some way, you could use [UIMutableUserNotificationAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMutableUserNotificationAction_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIMutableUserNotificationAction) to launch your app in the background and schedule further notifications.